# How would I SUM column values while excluding any that precede the text string "reset"?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a spreadsheet where the hours of wear for pieces of equipment are logged:

- Data is logged in new rows as additional wear-hours are put on the equipment.
- From time to time, equipment is replaced, and a text entry "reset" is added to the column and logging of the replacement continues below that entry.
- This may be repeated several times, and hours logged for equipment that was replaced is never removed.

How can I add the total hours logged in a column while excluding any entries that precede the very last instance of "reset"?

Sample Data

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Current** | **21** |
| **2** | Starting | 500 |
| **3** | Day 1 | 10 |
| **4** | Day 2 | RESET |
| **5** | Day 3 | 15 |
| **6** | Day 4 | 6 |

What formula would I put in `B1` that would add `B5:B` since `B2:B3` is followed by a "RESET" in `B4`?

Answer (score 0):

Given a column of values/resets in B2 downwards, the following in B1 will calculate the sum of the values after the last instance of 'reset':

```
=let(
array,tocol(B2:B,1),
lastreset,xmatch("reset",array,0,-1),
sum(chooserows(array,sequence(rows(array)-lastreset,1,lastreset+1))))
```

Comment: Presumably, there might not always be a "reset" in the column.  If that's the case, the error would need to be handled somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

## Formula

```
=LET(arr,SORT(B2:B,ROW(B2:B),0),
  SUM(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(arr,
    IFNA(MATCH("reset",arr,0),ROWS(arr)),1)))
```

## Explanation

1. `arr` stores column B in reverse order.
2. ARRAY_CONSTRAIN reduces the height of `arr` to just enough rows to include the *first* (now that it's reversed) instance of "reset", or, if "reset" is not found, IFNA returns the total number of rows in `arr`
3. The resulting array is passed to SUM

**NOTE:**
SUM ignores text and blanks so I didn't bother reducing the array an extra row to eliminate "reset", nor did I worry about the empty rows below the data.

---

## Functions

[ARRAY_CONSTRAIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3267036?hl=en) [IFNA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9365944?hl=en) [LET](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13190535?hl=en) [MATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378?hl=en) [ROW](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093316?hl=en) [ROWS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093382?hl=en) [SORT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093150?hl=en) [SUM](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093669?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

You can learn the QUERY formula below:

> =SUM(QUERY(B1:B,"Select B Where B is not null Offset "&MATCH("reset",B1:B,0)-1&" "))